# Include fields from a table function in a select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I'm running this query on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT 
   orr.Rate, orr.ID, orr.UserKey, fn.NetRate 
FROM 
   OngoingRate orr 
CROSS APPLY 
   dbo.GetRateNetView(orr.UserKey) as fn
WHERE 
   orr.UserKey = 5
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Please help

Comment: I've updated [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44912/1186) to include this scenario as well. Still I'm not sure why you had to restart SQL Server - compatibility level changes should take place immediately. Are you 100% certain you were running the query in the context of the database where you changed the compat level?

Comment: Aaron Bertrand: Im Positive, it worked after the restart

Answer (score 7):

The syntax you have is correct from SQL Server 2005 and up. You are using SQL Server 2008 so it should work just fine unless you have compatibility level for your database set to "SQL Server 2000 (80)".

Make sure you have compatibility level set to at least "SQL Server 2005 (90)".

Right-click on your database - Properties - Options

[image]

Comment: I was suspecting the same thing but I updated the compatibility level to SQL Server 2008(100). Let me restart sql server(just in case)

Comment: Hi Mikael, it turns out I had to restart the sql server service for the changes to take effect. Thanks for your contribution