# How to make SQL Server 2008 compatible to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I have to run the backup of SQL Server 2000 in SQL Server 2008.

While restoring the database from the `.bak` file, I got the error

> specified cast is invalid

After doing google I feel there is compatibility issue. Therefore I want to make the database compatibile to SQL Server 2000.

And run the below query

```
ALTER DATABASE  DBNAME 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80
```

but nothing help. Any help will be appreciated.
The complete error message is :

```
Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

------------------------------
Program Location:<br/>
  at <br/>Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.PopulateGridWithBackupSetsFromDevices()<br/>
   at <br/>Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.GetBackupSetsFromDevices()<br/>
   at <br/>Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.textDeviceSelected_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Text(String value)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_Text(String value)<br/>
   at <br/>Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.bu<br/>ttonSelectDevice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button,Int32 clicks)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)<br/>
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, <br/><IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)<br/>
```

Comment: The error message you posted does have much information. Can you show us the restore query(if you used) and complete error message.

Comment: We have similar issue - we use DB in 2000 compatibility mode on MS SQL 2005 - we have issues in ORDER BY section. You have to find which is the query that gives the error and post its code so we can help.

Comment: how are we supposed to help on an error without the code? wich cast is invalid? beware: posting the single line with the cast is not helpful, a little context is needed.

Comment: have a look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80) to understand why your best bet is to install a separate instance of sql 2000 or update the code and raise the compatibility level to a recent one.

Comment: This is happening when restoring the database ? What is the compatibility mode on the source database? You are not able to restore a database in compatability mode  8 on SQL Server 2008

Comment: yes @Sporri ,it is now sql server 2000 compatibility mode on source database.

Comment: @poojasharma, are you saying you get the cast error during the restore?  Try using a T-SQL `RESTORE` command instead of the GUI.

Comment: Install latest version of **SSMS** or your **USE TSQL** to restore backup.

Comment: hi all , i have used the following command :RESTORE DATABASE Dynamic FROM DISK='C:\DynamicStagingBackup.bak' .<br/>. but it is giving me the error message : Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'Dynamic' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: i am now able to restore the database without any error in sql server 2005 , but the problem is restoring is taking too much time. it has been running since two days. i am not able to fire any query, it is saying database is is the middle of restoring.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following link there is a step missing:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012.aspx

- You must first **update your SQL Server 2000 by upgrading to SP4** before making a backup to restore onto SQL Server 2008.

The TechNet link refers to moving from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012, but the *first step* is moving from SQL Server 2000 **SP4** to SQL Server 2008.

If going all the way to a current version of SQL Server you will have to make the migration in two steps:

- Step 1: Make a first migration from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 for instance. You need to be on SQL Server 2000 **SP4**.
- Step 2: Make a second migration from SQL Server 2008 to 2012.

Comment: the error itself is related to GUI `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI`, I dont think your answer applies to this question. I would recon that if OP uses the latest version of SSMS or uses TSQL to restore then it would work.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but it seems unlikely that using the SQL Server 2000 tools to restore to a SQL Server 2008 would be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments and answers.
After doing a little bit more GOOGLE, i get to know that sql 2000 can only be restored on sql 2005 database. the backup which are taken from sql 2005 and upwards can be restored on higher versoins after setting the compatibilty mode. 
but still i have an issue that it is taking so much time to restore even after i have used the option no recovery .
can someone also help me to come out from this.