# Stats Maintenance after Restoring to Newer SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

What's the ideal (or necessary) sequence of call when restoring a SQL Server 2012 backup onto a SQL Server 2014 instance and updating the compatibility level?

```
-- Update Statistics for all tables
EXEC sp_MSforEachtable 'Update Statistics ? with FULLSCAN';

-- Update page and row counts in catalogviews
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE('MY_DATABASE') ;

-- Change DB Compatibility level
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'MY_DATABASE', '120';
```

I'm not sure if the db compatibility level effects the stats or simple the engine on the server. If the db compatibility level influences stats than it should be done before update stats. Also unclear if UPDATEUSAGE is still recommend and if it should be before update stats as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to Update statistics as well as compatibility level to the latest version of sql server (provided your application supports it and you have done proper full business life cycle testing). I have written about [**full list of steps when moving from lower version to higher version**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783)

As a side note, please don't use `sp_MSforEachtable` - Its not supported. There is a [clever way of doing it](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Compatibility level matters - see [What is the actual behavior of compatibility level 80?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44912/8783) and [Clinging to old compatibility levels](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-old-compatibility-levels/) form Aaron Bertrand

Comment: Do the sp_dbcmptlevel before update stats? And you don't recommend UpdateUsage? Good to be explicit about the lifecycle testing on the compatibility level.

Comment: You should **not use** `sp_dbcmptlevel`, instead use `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120`. Also, after the database restore, it is **not** required to run `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` unless  you suspect [incorrect values are being returned by sp_spaceused](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx).

Comment: At the risk of running to much into a tangent, why not the sp? The help text, at a glance, shows it basically a wrapper for the ALTER DB statement with some validation.

Comment: `sp_dbcmptlevel` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx) - This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level instead.