# Upgrade a database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, upgrade

I have database in SQL Server 2008 R2. I took a backup of this database and restored that on a SQL Server 2014 server.  However, some of the database queries are not looking compatible to the new version.

For example `*=` operator is throwing errors in SQL Server 2014.

I don't want to change each query where I get issue.  Is there any way to upgrade the older version of SQL Server backup to work with the newer version of database?

Comment: You won't ever be able to run `*=` queries on SQL Server 2014. Those require 80 compatibility mode (see [the second item in the table here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.105).aspx)), and SQL Server 2014 [does not support 80 compatibility mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.120).aspx). So, you need to either not upgrade to SQL Server 2014, or fix your queries. There is no magic "ignore that this syntax no longer works" switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot restore a SQL Server 2000 database onto a SQL Server 2014 instance. You need to restore to SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2 instance first, then take a backup of that database which you can then restore to 2014.

There a lot of features from SQL Server 2000 that have been discontinued in SQL Server 2014.  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) list for the details about what features have been discontinued, and what to use as replacements.

Unfortunately, you have no choice but to re-code queries that use the ancient `=*` or `*=` join syntax.

[SQLMag](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-select-steps-migrate-sql-server-2000-sql-server-2014) has a great article on how to do the migration.

Comment: Is there any tool to convert old version sql query to sql server 2014?

Comment: @user3783446 I don't know of any tools that can convert a `*=` / `=*` query to a proper join, insert semi-colons in all the right places accurately, etc. There are several tools that can help *identify* those, like upgrade advisor, best practices analyzer, SQLCop, etc (and I tried to point out a bunch of actual behavior changes in [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44912/1186)). But moving from 2000 will require some actual work.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mspfe/2012/12/05/sql-server-upgrade-advisor-considerations-when-upgrading-from-sql-2000-to-sql-2012/) and use upgrade advisor.

Comment: Some of the queries are of compatibility level=80. ex. *= operator and starting CTE without using ; before it. So, these kind of queries are not working in sql server 2014.