# PIVOT with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, pivot

I have SQL Server table data returning the below data. (Green text is a note on the value of each cell in 'Outcome' column)

[image]

I want to PIVOT that query result so that it uses the latest 'ReceivedTime' for those same filenames. And the Outcome values should be split into separate columns - with a COUNT of each occurrence.

[image]

Here is my code so far. However, this returns multiple rows rather than grouping by filename.
What do I need to change?

```
DECLARE @TmpTable AS TABLE
(
    Filename varchar(80),
    ReceivedTime datetime,
    Outcome int NULL
);
INSERT INTO @TmpTable
VALUES
    ('FileABC','2018/06/29 03:34', 1),
    ('FileABC','2018/06/28 11:01', 3),
    ('FileABC','2018/06/28 09:30', 2),
    ('FileABC','2018/06/28 05:23', NULL),
    ('FileABC','2018/06/28 16:21', 3);

SELECT 
     Filename as 'LatestReceivedTime'
    ,[-1] AS 'NotProcessing'
    ,[0] AS 'InProgress'
    ,[2] AS 'Warning'
    ,[3] AS 'Failed'
    ,[1] AS 'Success'
FROM 
(
    SELECT x.Filename, x.ReceivedTime, COALESCE(x.Outcome, -1) AS 'Outcome'
    FROM @TmpTable x

) x
PIVOT
(  
COUNT(Outcome)  
FOR Outcome IN ([-1], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some aggregation:

```
SELECT 
     [Filename] 
    ,MAX(ReceivedTime) as 'LatestReceivedTime'
    ,SUM([-1]) AS 'NotProcessing'
    ,SUM([0]) AS 'InProgress'
    ,SUM([2]) AS 'Warning'
    ,SUM([3]) AS 'Failed'
    ,SUM([1]) AS 'Success'
FROM 
(
    SELECT x.Filename, x.ReceivedTime, COALESCE(x.Outcome, -1) AS 'Outcome'
    FROM @TmpTable x

) x
PIVOT
(  
COUNT(Outcome)  
FOR Outcome IN ([-1], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4])  
) AS PivotTable

GROUP BY [Filename];
```

Comment: Get this error: "Column 'PivotTable.-1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: It runs successfully for me, check for missing comma/semicolon in wrong place?

Comment: @Kevin Did you wrap the [-1] in an aggregate as well?

Comment: @Kevin Also you are using a 10-year old database platform, is it possible it's still set to work with syntax from an 18-year old database platform? Check the compatibility level and make sure it's not 80. If it is, don't just change it willy-nilly, you could restore a backup and update the compat level there, then try this same syntax. If it works you may have to consider all the testing involved with changing it on the primary database. I talked about several impacts of the 80 compat level here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44908/1186