# List users permissions to tables and schemas on MSSQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions

[List all permissions for a given role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role) has a nice query for listing users and their roles on a DB.

How could we list all tables and users with their permissions on these tables?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. To me, it is confusing about what you are asking.

Comment: check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41234/how-to-find-which-tables-and-views-a-user-has-access-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

SELECT ST.NAME, su.name, 
CASE WHEN SYP.[ACTION] = 193 THEN 'SELECT' WHEN SYP.[ACTION] = 195 THEN 'INSERT' WHEN SYP.[ACTION] = 196 THEN 'DELETE' WHEN SYP.[ACTION] = 197 THEN 'UPDATE' ELSE CAST(SYP.[ACTION] AS CHAR(3)) END AS Permission
FROM
SYS.SYSPROTECTS SYP INNER JOIN
SYS.SYSUSERS SU
ON SU.uid = SYP.UID
INNER JOIN SYS.SYSOBJECTS SO
ON SO.id = SYP.id
INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES ST
ON ST.object_id = SO.id

Comment: tnx a lot! It seems this query lists somehow explicit permissions and not implicit/inherited ones.